# I am getting a nullPointerException on my URL link

Tags: java, swing, url, nullpointerexception, imageicon

I am trying to build a toolbar for this math practice program that I wrote. I am trying to get an image from a folder called images. It will not allow me to. It gives me a NullPointerException, I will mark the lines with *** where the Exception points to.

```
public JButton makeNavigationButton( String imageName, String toolTipText ) {
   String imgLocation = "images/" + imageName + ".jpg";
   URL imageURL = MathPractice.class.getResource(imgLocation);
   JButton button = new JButton();
   button.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
   //button.addActionListener(this);
   button.setIcon( new ImageIcon( imageURL )); //************* NPE here
   return button;
}
```

Comment: Do you think all that code is relevant? Don't make our lives difficult.

Comment: fixed it, I hope its enough to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [Class.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources
>   associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class
>   loader of the class. This method delegates to this object's class
>   loader. If this object was loaded by the bootstrap class loader, the
>   method delegates to ClassLoader.getSystemResource(java.lang.String).
>
> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
>   Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
> ```
>     modified_package_name/name
> ```
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

With Eclipse, if the directory `images` is in `bin`, it will be found. Move `images` into  `src/images`.